# Python flask blueprint registration route for different arguments

Tags: python, flask

I was able to call route_category method on invoking GET /category/category but I was not able to call route_category_with_id on invoking GET /category/category?2; I observed that I always get into method route_category even thou I invoke /category/category/2; How can we fix this?

I declared Python init file for blueprint as below

```
from flask import Blueprint
blueprint = Blueprint(
     'category_blueprint',
      __name__,
      url_prefix='/category',
      template_folder='templates',
      static_folder='static' 
 )
```

and I have routes.py file for the category declared as below

```
  @blueprint.route('/<template>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
  def route_category(template):
      do_something

  @blueprint.route('/<template>/<int:id>', methods=["GET"])
  def route_category_with_id(template):
      do_something_with_id
```

The routes.py got registered as below in python main program

```
    module = import_module('category.routes'.format(module_name))
    app.register_blueprint(module.blueprint)
```

How to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "I was not able to invoke route category"? Does it throw an error? If so, which? Does it not do what you want it to do? If so, what do you expect it to do and what does it do?

Comment: If I call http://<ip-address>/category/ it should invoke route_category method and If I call http://<ip-address>/category?2 it should invoke route_category_with_id method. I don't get any error rather I always get into "route_category" method irrespective of call to http://<ip-address>/category or http://<ip-address>/category?2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request [args (request.args)](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.args) are not the same as route [variables](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#url-route-registrations).

Meaning, `route_category_with_id` is looking for:

```
http://<ip-address>/category/2
```

To keep the `?2` syntax, you will need to turn this into `?key=value`, and access it in your view by using `request.args.get('key')`

Answer (score 0):

You should/can set multiple routes to single method

So code should be like that;

```
@blueprint.route('/<template>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@blueprint.route('/<template>/<int:id>', methods=["GET"])
  def route_category(template, id=None):
      if id is None:
          # do_something
          pass
      else:
          # do_something_with_id
          pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The following scenarios should make things clear for you:

1. When you call `http://example.com/category`, it invokes your `route_category` method.
2. When you call `http://example.com/category?2`, it invokes your `route_category`, with a query string consisting of `2`. What comes after the `?` is called a query string - you can access it in Flask with `flask.request.args`. It should look like `?key=value`, then `flask.request.args.get("key")`
3. When you call `http://example.com/category/2` -> only then it invokes your `route_category_with_id`, because here you have passed a route parameter.